# torch.masked_scatter result did not meet expectations

Tags: pytorch

my pytorch code:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[0.3992, 0.2908, 0.9004, 0.4850, 0.6004],
            [0.5735, 0.9006, 0.6797, 0.4152, 0.1732]])
print(x.shape)
mask = torch.tensor([[False, False,  True, False,  True],
            [ True,  True,  True, False, False]])
print(mask.shape)
y = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
print(y.shape)
y.masked_scatter_(mask, x)
print(y)
```

result is:

```
torch.Size([2, 5])
torch.Size([2, 5])
torch.Size([2, 5])
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3992, 0.0000, 0.2908],
        [0.9004, 0.4850, 0.6004, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

i think the result answer is:

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.9004, 0.0000, 0.6004],
        [0.5375, 0.9006, 0.6797, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

my pytorch version is pytorch1.4

Answer (score 3):

You are right, this is confusing and there is virtually no documentation.

However, the way scatter works (as you have discovered) is that the `i`th `True` in a row is given the `i`th value from the source. So not the value corresponding to the position of the `True`.

Luckily what you are trying to do can easily be achieved using the normal indexing notation:

```
>>> y[mask] = x[mask]
>>> y
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.9004, 0.0000, 0.6004],
        [0.5735, 0.9006, 0.6797, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

Comment: Any way to achieve this out-of-place, to make it work in the backward pass?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is maybe this:

```py
y = torch.where(mask, x, 0.)
```

[`masked_scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.masked_scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.masked_scatter_) works differently. I think it helps most to see this as the inverse function of [`masked_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html).